# Setting and reading Windows ENV variable in node?

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd

In my package.json I have this entry :

```
"runMe": "set  AAA=3 && echo %AAA%"
```

which looks like that :

[image]

In general, I want to set env variable, and to read it at the next section...

I'm expecting to get in console: `3`

But instead I get this `%AAA%` :

[image]

**Question:**

How can I get the `echo` to show `3`? I prefer ( please) not to use third-party libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For same section, try:

---

```bat
"runMe": "set  \"AAA=3\" && cmd /v/c echo %AAA%"
"runMe": "(set  \"AAA=3\") && cmd /v/c echo %AAA%"

rem :: or :: 

"runMe": "set  \"AAA=3\" && cmd /v/c echo !AAA!"
"runMe": "(set  \"AAA=3\") && cmd /v/c echo !AAA!"
```

---

for to read it at the next and same section, you need use global variable

---

```bat
"runMe": "setx  AAA 3 && for /f tokens^=3 %i in ('reg query HKCU\Environment ^|find aaa')do echo=%i"
```

For cmd command line, remove the scaping in **`\`**":

```bat
set  "AAA=3" && cmd /v/c echo %AAA%
(set  "AAA=3") && cmd /v/c echo %AAA%

rem :: or :: 

set  "AAA=3" && cmd /v/c echo !AAA!
(set  "AAA=3") && cmd /v/c echo !AAA!
```

---

<sub>Sorry my limited **English**</sub>

Comment: btw ive managet to do it with `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` in a batch file with `!var!` which causes it to be late binded

Comment: Direct in cmd : the SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion == cmd /v --> cmd /v/c echo !AAA!"

Comment: btw - not it works in node but not in cmd. I mean why does this `set  \"AAA=3\" && cmd /v/c echo %AAA%` doesnt work straight in cmd ?

Comment: \" scape coma for send the command to cmd.exe subsystem, this one in cmd: set "AAA=3" && cmd /v/c echo %AAA%